# Boot EC2 EBS volume locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I want to do some testing with an EC2 instance, but to download it to my PC and run it locally on VirtualBox/KVM or the like. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. EC2 instances run on a customised Red Hat Xen layer whose AMIs are tailored specifically to that platform. Those images cannot be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use VMWare to create an image, work on it and then upload it to EC2.
Amazon [introduced this feature](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/12/amazon-vm-import-bring-your-vmware-images-to-the-cloud.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AmazonWebServicesBlog+%28Amazon+Web+Services+Blog%29) in Dec 2010. However, this will only be useful to you if you work on Windows Server 2008 SP2. See the [Amazon VM Import Page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/)

Answer (score 1):

As of mid 2013, VMware imports to EC2 are not restricted only to windows.

"You can import VMware ESX and VMware Workstation VMDK images, Citrix Xen VHD images and Microsoft Hyper-V VHD images for Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.1-6.5 (using Cloud Access), Centos 5.1-6.5, Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, and Debian 6.0.0-6.0.8, 7.0.0-7.2.0. You can export previously imported EC2 instances to VMware ESX VMDK, VMware ESX OVA, Microsoft Hyper-V VHD or Citrix Xen VHD file formats. We plan to support import for additional operating systems, versions and virtualization infrastructure products in the future."

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you imported the image, you may simply use the EC2 CLI to export the image as an OVA or VMDK. [AWS Official Blog entry](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/vm-export-for-ec2/) & [EC2 CLI command info](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateInstanceExportTask.html)

If not, you can follow the instructions [here](https://www.geekandi.com/2014/04/13/amazon-linux-vagrant-box-images/) to convert the image to a VMDK. The instructions are for Vagrant, but only part 3 of the instructions are vagrant-specific, so you may simply skip that part to stop with a working VMDK.

See also this [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/374861/converting-an-ec2-ami-to-vmdk-image).