# Can we mount a AMI snapshot to a local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

1. I want to determine a snapshot associated with a given AMI-ID, then mount a copy of that snapshot onto the local machine(and not AWS Instance).
2. I am using boto to get the snapshot-id from the AMI-ID

   image = conn.get_image(ami)
   snapshot_id = image.block_device_mapping.current_value.snapshot_id

Is it possible to mount a snapshot to a local machine and not a EC2-instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For EBS backed AMIs there isn't a way to accomplish this that I'm aware of.

With an Instance Store-Backed AMI and quite a bit of effort, yes. See [this blog post.](http://weaponshot.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/downloading-an-ami-to-local/)

Other helpful resources:

[Eight-Bit Guru's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145286/boot-ec2-ebs-volume-locally)
[S3 vs. EBS backed instances](http://blog.magpiebrain.com/2010/07/19/aws-s3-vs-ebs-backed-instances/)
[Selecting between EBS and Instance Store-Backed AMI](http://www.newvem.com/choosing-between-ebs-backed-and-instance-store-backed-ami/)

Comment: Actaully not sure about the type of AMI but from the console under that particular AMI, Root Device Type: ebs.

Comment: Then as far as I know mounting it locally is not an option. If I come across any new information, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: your answer is helpful, I am a newbie to Amazon services